# Use Ghostscript with WAMP

Tags: wampserver, ghostscript

After I downloaded Ghostscript for Windows and successfully installed it, I wonder now how can I make WAMP recognize it so I can use it with `shell_exec` ?

I specify that I added the Ghostscript directory in the system path and when I run the command line, it works fine.

I have WAMPServer 2.5 and Windows 7.

Comment: Did you install imagick and ghostscript or just ghostscript

Comment: No just Ghostscript